# How do I make multiple carousels on a page using HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'd been following and editing a w3schools tutorial for putting multiple carousels on one page, and it works great for having 2 carousels but I need more carousels than that. I've been trying different things for like 3 days and I really can't figure out a solution, any help would be great!

```js
let slideIndex = [1, 1];
let slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3", "mySlides4", "mySlides5"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
showSlides(1, 3);
showSlides(1, 4);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  let i;
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/*  CAROUSELS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.mySlides1,
.mySlides2,
.mySlides3,
.mySlides4,
.mySlides5 {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Caption text */

.Captiontext {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00000077
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #A58473;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a grey background color */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: #00000077;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="iteminfo">
    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="Captiontext">
        <p class="p" style="text-align: center;">/</p>
      </div>
      <img src="./icon.png" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="iteminfo">
    <div class="mySlides3">
      <div class="Captiontext">
        <p class="p" style="text-align: center;">/</p>
      </div>
      <img src="./logo.png" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML: (for a working carousel, one of the first 2 carousels)

HTML: (for a broken carousel, the 3rd on the page)

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="iteminfo">
        <div class="mySlides3">
            <div class="Captiontext"><p class="p" style="text-align: center;">/</p></div>
            <img src="./logo.png" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any and all help would be highly appreciated!! I can provide more parts of my code if needed.
With each carousel, the `plusSlides` and class are different. For example, the first carousel (working) has `plusSlides(-1, 0)` and `(1, 0)`. The other working carousel has `plusSlides(-1, 1)` and `(1, 1)` so I presumed upping that last number for each carousel would be necessary but I still can't get it to work.

I have bootstrap also on this page, so if I can't get this carousel to work like this I'll try a different method, but I really want this to work. Like I said I've been trying with this on and off for 3 days

Comment: Try adding your code as a snippet with HTML, your script and any CSS.

Comment: I made a snippet of your code but it throws errors when you run it

Answer (score 0):

`slideIndex` gets mixed up between carousels.
You may want to keep the state of the currently shown slide in each carousel in a separate variable.

This is an example that uses bootstrap carousels (based on w3schools [example here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_carousel.php)):

```html
<base href="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Carousel 1 -->
<div id="demo1" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>

  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>




<!-- Carousel 2 -->
<div id="demo2" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo2" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo2" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo2" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>

  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo2" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo2" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>




<!-- Carousel 3 -->
<div id="demo3" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo3" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo3" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo3" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>

  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo3" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo3" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

demo: https://livecodes.io/?x=id/urxz5fzzpn2